# ruby array mapping dual array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, multidimensional-array

,I know how to transform the data I want into one array.

Ie from a model holding geocordinates in one line:

```
Place.all.map(&:latitude)

[12.34, 12.34, ...]
```

How can I transform it to make a nested dual array with both latitude and longitude

```
ie [[12.34,23.34],[23.45,12,23],...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Place.all.map{ |place| [place.latitude, place.longitude] }
```

Sidenotes:

- `all` queries are db killers.
- if you only need two fields, consider using `select`

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really using :all.  Just for the example, thanks.  I have to wait 13 minutes to accept your answer. ;-)